# QAction icon is not showing in Qtoolbar

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside2, qresource

I have a problem with QToolbar and QAction. I'm trying to show an action with a icon but the icon is not showing.

This is my qrc and code example (I'm using PySide2):

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC><RCC version="1.0">
<qresource prefix="/iconos">
    <file alias="vista-inicial.svg">iconos/cubo.svg</file>
    <file alias="cubo.png">iconos/3d.png</file>
</qresource>
</RCC>
```

```
import sys
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui


class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        toolbar = QtWidgets.QToolBar()
        toolbar.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonIconOnly)
        toolbar.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(24, 24))
        accion_vista_inicial = QtWidgets.QAction(QtGui.QIcon(":iconos/cubo.png"), "Vista Inicial", self)

        toolbar.addAction(accion_vista_inicial)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(toolbar)
        layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel("Test"))

        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.show()


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    test = MyWidget()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And finally a little screenshot:

[image]

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc Sorry, I updated the question.

Comment: I think you might also need `accion_vista_inicial.setParent(toolbar)`

Comment: @ArthurTacca I tried it, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the .qrc into .py and import it into your script:

```
pyside2-rcc resource.qrc -o resource_rc.py
```

```
import sys

from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

import resource_rc

# ...
```

Comment: I did it, but it's not working at the moment. The command runs fine, and find the files, but it's seem that are not found later.

Comment: @Eduardo in my test it works, how are you running it? What are the characteristics of your environment: OS, python version, pyside2 version, etc? What do you mean by *but it's seem that are not found later.*?

Comment: I'm running PySide2==5.15.0 / shiboken2==5.15.0. with Python 3.8.3 (In a virtual environment). What I mean is that when I run the qrc command it finds the files, but then when I want to access them it seems that they do not exist or I am doing something wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was importing the generated .py file in a wrong way. This is the correct answer.